# R loop to extract data from excel files and save outputs in separate dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, assign, readxl

I would like to loop through a set of excel files in a folder (let's imagine the folder contains 5 excel files). Each excel file contains different data but with the same structure, that looks like this:

| Col_01 | Col_02 | Col_03 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.5 | 0.2 | 0.1 |
| 0.8 | 1.2 | 3.1 |
| 0.1 | 0.9 | 0.4 |

I'd like to extract a specific range of data (let's imagine the range A2:C4) from each one of these excels, and then save the outputs in different data frames. I created this code:

```
library(readxl)

# Take the list of excel files from a folder
list_excelfiles <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')

# Define codes that will be used in the output names of the dataframes created
codes <- c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005")

# Start loop
for (x in list_excelfiles) {
  # Define the range of data to extract from the excel files
  range <- c("A2:C4")
  
  # Use readxl package to read the specific range of data from excel, and save the extracted range into a dataframe 
  x <- read_excel(x, sheet = NULL, range = range, col_types = "numeric")

  # Assign a name to the data frames created
  for (i in codes)  {
     assign(paste("Data_", i, sep = "_"), x) 
     }
```

At this point the loop should create 5 dataframes (named Data_001, Data_002, etc.) containing 5 set of data. Unfortunately the code above creates the dataframes with the correct naming (e.g. Data_001, Data_002, etc.), but the content of all the dataframes is always the same (namely: all the dataframes report the data taken from the last excel). Can anybody help?

Comment: Please provide some example data so we can reproduce the error, the thing I am noticing is you are double using x in your for loop.

Comment: @szmple I edited the post with more info on how the excels look like (unfortunately I cannot upload/attach the excels directly to the post). Hope this helps

Comment: You run `for (i in codes)  { assign(paste("Data_", i, sep = "_"), x) }` for each file. That means you reassign all variables each time. You don't want to have this loop inside the outer loop. It's really better not to use a loop and not to use `assign()` and just collect data in a loop. something like `Data <- lapply(list_excelfiles, function(x) read_excel(x, sheet = NULL, range = "A2:C4", col_types = "numeric")`. That will give you a list you can access like `Data[[1]]`, `Data[[2]]`, etc which is much easier to work with than separate variables in your global environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that for every single excel file you are redefining all of the Data_code variables as containing the content for that excel file. So for the final excel file it overwrites all the variables as using that excel file's content.

To get around this you just need to do the assign once in the main for loop e.g. in the code below I edited it so that it goes through each excel file and for each one:

1. loads the data
2. creates a new variable for this data called Data_00i where i is some number which starts at 1 and goes up to the number of excel files

```r
library(readxl)

# Take the list of excel files from a folder
list_excelfiles <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')

# Start loop
for (i in seq(length(list_excelfiles))) {
  # Define the range of data to extract from the excel files
  range <- c("A2:C4")
  
  # Use readxl package to read the specific range of data from excel, and save the extracted range into a dataframe 
  x <- read_excel(list_excelfiles[i], sheet = NULL, range = range, col_types = "numeric")

  # Assign a name to the data frames created
  assign(paste("Data_00", i), x) 
}
```